# Delete local storage data during/before uninstallation of the window application using electron-wix-msi

Tags: electron, wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, electron-wix-msi

I'm building a Windows application with `elctron.js` and npm package `electron-wix-msi` which uses local storage and its working fine but now, I want when somebody uninstalls then the data in the local storage should be clear. If the user re-installs it, they cannot use the previous data.

How can I do such a thing?

my code is:

```
const { MSICreator } = require('electron-wix-msi');
const path = require('path');

const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, "./assets/logo/logo.ico");
const msiCreator = new MSICreator({
  appDirectory: path.join(__dirname, "./dist/windows/chatbot-win32-x64"),
  outputDirectory: path.join(__dirname, "./"),

  // Configure metadata
  description: 'Chatbot',
  exe: 'chatbot',
  name: 'ChatBot',
  manufacturer: 'manoj',
  version: '1.0.0',
  appIconPath: path.join(__dirname, "./assets/logo/logo.ico"),
  features: {
      autoLaunch: true,
      autoUpdate: true
  },

  // Configure installer User Interface
  ui: {
      chooseDirectory: true
  },
});

// 4. Create a .wxs template file
msiCreator.create().then(function(){
  // Step 5: Compile the template to a .msi file
  msiCreator.compile();
});
```